# Change div id after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to change the id of my div after the page is loaded. I have a mixture of HTML and CakePHP code, so doing it all dynamically from the start is a challenge for me.

Here's just one of the instances I'm struggling with.

```
<div class = "ui-widget" id="container">
<?php
echo $this->Form-          >input($fieldName,array('div'=>false,'label'=>array('id'=>'autocompleteLabe     l'),     'id'=>$fieldName.'_selList'/*,'options'=>array('')*/,'style'=>'display:none    '));
?>
<input id = "autocomplete" style ="" autocomplete = "on">
<label id = "autotop"></label>
</div>
```

The div with id "container" needs to be dynamic, but I can't figure out a way to set a dynamic id in HTML, so I'm trying to change the id after the page is loaded. This does not work however.

I tried both jQuery and JavaScript to do this change, but no luck. This is the JavaScript line I tried without success.

```
var container = document.getElementById("div_id").id = newID;
```

newID is a field I declared, containing a string with the id I wish to use.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're trying to change the ID of div with ID `container`, wouldn't you be better doing `document.getElementById("container")`? Also, at the end of that call, `container` == `newID`, not the container DOM element as I would have expected given the variable name

Comment: Other than RGraham's point above, provided your JavaScript code runs **after** that element exists, that code should work. (You don't need the `var container =` part of it, though; and note that with it there, what you get in your `container` variable is the value of `newID`, not a reference to the element.)

Answer (score 0):

```
       $('#container').attr('id','id_new');
```

Comment: It would be better to add some explanation

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood it you fetch a new ID from some input and want to set the id of container to the new id?

if thats the case try using this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var getContainer = $('#autocomplete').prev('div');
  $(getContainer).attr('id', newID);
});
```

Comment: #autocomplete does exists
`<input id = "autocomplete" style ="" autocomplete = "on">`
and i use this to get the div because i dont know if the class is unique and u cant use the ID since the id always changes. except u could use a var that always saves the recent ID and just request the div from the var

Answer (score 0):

Simple javascript solution

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("container").id = 'newID';   
}
```

Looks like you forgot the single quote around your new id or if you what to use newID as a javascript variable do this

```
var newID = <?= $IdNameFromServer ?>
```